# Finding $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} (x_0 x_1 \cdots x_n)\sqrt{n}$ where $x_{n+1}=x_n^3-x_n^2+1$, $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math

> **Problem.** Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence defined by $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n^3-x_n^2+1$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$. Find
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (x_0 x_1 \cdots x_n)\sqrt{n}.$$

According to the answer sheet, this limit equals $1$. However, I can't manage to solve it. Here is what I've done.

Obviously, $x_{n+1}-x_n=(x_n-1)^2(x_n+1)>0$ (it is easy to observe that all the terms of the sequence are positive), so $(x_n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence.

Let us now prove by induction on $n$ that $x_n<1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$. The base case is obvious, so suppose it holds for $n$ and prove it for $n+1$. $x_{n+1}=x_n^2(x_n-1)+1<1$ by the induction hypothesis and we are done.

Hence, $(x_n)$ is monotone and bounded, so it is convergent. It is easy to see now that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=1$.

Now I pretty much got stuck. I tried to use the epsilon definition of a limit, trying to exploit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=1$, but it didn't help. Maybe I should use Stolz–Cesàro on the limit that I want to compute?

Answer (score 6):

Let's note as
$$y_n=(x_0x_1...x_n)\sqrt{n} \tag{1}$$
From $$\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_{n}-1}=x_n^2$$
we have
$$\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_{n}-1}\cdot\frac{x_{n}-1}{x_{n-1}-1}=\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_{n-1}-1}=x_n^2 x_{n-1}^2$$
then
$$\frac{x_{n+1}-1}{\frac{1}{2}-1}=x_n^2 x_{n-1}^2...x_0^2 \iff
x_n^2 x_{n-1}^2...x_0^2=2(1-x_{n+1})\iff$$
$$y_n=\sqrt{2n(1-x_{n+1})} \tag{2}$$

---

> **Proposition 1.** For $n\geq1$ $$x_n \geq \frac{2n-1}{2n}$$

To begin with, $f(x)=x^3-x^2+1$ is ascending on $\left[\frac{2}{3},1\right]$, easy to check by [taking the derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3Dx%5E3%20-x%5E2%20%2B1).

By induction

- $x_1=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1=\frac{7}{8}>\frac{2\cdot1-1}{2\cdot1}=\frac{1}{2}$
- $x_2=\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^3-\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^2+1=\frac{463}{512}>\frac{2\cdot2-1}{2\cdot2}=\frac{3}{4}>\frac{2}{3}$
- now let's assume $x_n>\frac{2n-1}{2n}>\frac{2}{3}$, then ($f(x)$ is ascending!) $$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)\geq f\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)=\\
  \frac{8n^3-4n^2+4n-1}{8n^3}\geq \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$$ since $$\frac{8n^3-4n^2+4n-1}{8n^3}-\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}=\frac{3n-1}{8n^3(n + 1)}>0$$ [not too difficult to check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288%20n%5E3%20-%204%20n%5E2%20%2B%204%20n%20-%201%29%2F%288%20n%5E3%29%20-%282n%2B1%29%2F%282n%2B2%29).

And we are done. As a result, from $(2)$
$$0<y_n\leq \sqrt{\frac{2n}{2n+2}}<1\tag{3}$$

---

> **Proposition 2.** For $n\geq1$ $$y_{n+1} > y_n$$

From $(1)$
$$\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=x_{n+1}\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} \tag{4}$$
$$\overset{\text{Pr1}}{\geq} 
\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}=
\frac{2n+1}{2\sqrt{n(n+1)}}>1$$

---

**The sequence $(y_n)_{n>0}$** is bounded and ascending, so it **has a limit**. Is it $1$ though? We will notice that

$$\frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x_n^2 (1-x_n)}=\frac{1}{x_n^2}+\frac{1}{x_n}+\frac{1}{1-x_n}$$ then
$$\frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{1-x_n}=\frac{1}{x_n^2}+\frac{1}{x_n}\leq ...$$
using **Proposition 1**
$$...\leq \left(\frac{2n}{2n-1}\right)^2+\frac{2n}{2n-1}=
\left(1+\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)^2+1+\frac{1}{2n-1}=\\
2+\frac{3}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}\leq
2+\frac{4}{2n-1}\leq 2+\frac{2}{n-1}$$
[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence)
$$\frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{1-x_2}=
\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{1-x_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{1-x_k}\right)\leq\\
2(n-2)+2\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k-1}=2(n-2)+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$$
Basically (where $C$-const)
$$\frac{1}{1-x_{n+1}}\leq 2n+2\log{(n-1)}+C$$
and using $(2)$ and $(3)$
$$1>y_n\geq \sqrt{\frac{2n}{2n+2\log{(n-1)}+C}}\to1, n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to previous MSE questions including
[question 2675217](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2675217),
[question 2776443](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2776443),
[question 2861768](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2861768/).

Define the recursion
$$ a_{n+1}=f(a_n)\;\;\text{ where }\;\; f(x):=x(1-x)^2. \tag{1}$$
Define the sequence $\, x_n := 1-a_n.\,$ Verify that
$\, x_{n+1}=x_n^3-x_n^2+1.\,$

Assume an asymptotic expansion
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  p_k(c,z)y^{k+1},
\;\; y := 1/n,\quad z := \log(y) \tag{2}$$
where $\,p_k(c,z)\,$ is a
polynomial of degree $\,k\,$ in $\,c\,$ and $\,z.\,$

Substitute equation $(2)$ into equation $(1)$ and
solve for the polynomials $\,p_k\,$ to get
$$ p_0\!=\!\frac12,\, p_1\!=\!\frac{c\!+\!3z}8,\,
p_2\!=\!\frac{(5\!+\!3c\!+\!c^2)\!+\!
(9\!+\!6c)z\!+\!9z^2}{32}. \tag{3} $$

Define the sequence
$$y_n:=(x_0x_1...x_n)\sqrt{n}. \tag{4} $$
Use equation $(1)$ and the definition of $\,x_n\,$ to verify that
$$ y_n=\sqrt{na_{n+1}/a_0}. \tag{5}$$

Use equation $(2)$ to get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = \sqrt{\frac{p_0}{a_0}} = \frac1{\sqrt{2a_0}}. \tag{6}$$
When $\,x_0=a_0=\frac12,\,$ the limit is $1$. Also, $\,c\approx -8.205896246.$